# Access Children with XPATH

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I have a problem trying to find element with XPath in Selenium (Python). I want to do two actions : first, to access child element of parent (which is a sub-sub child), and then access next sibling tag to do the same.

```
<div class="A">

  <div class="non-desired"></div>

  //First Access to B
  <div class="B">
    //In order to treat C
    <div class="C"></div>
  </div>

  // And then doing the same for all next B elements
  <div class="B"></div>

   ...

  <div class="B"></div>

</div>
```

I want to access the first B class (which is the 2nd child of the parent div), in order to access to the C class. And then after it's done, access to the second B class and do the same.. the third B class and do the same... and so on.

I know how to do basic XPATH but i'm lost. What i've done is :

```
//div[@class='A']/following-sibling::div
```

Comment: B's are children of A, not siblings.

Comment: Yes but it's also about siblings with is the next tag of the child

Answer (score 0):

To access B you can use this xpath:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div[2]')
```

which will give you 2nd element of your B. If you want the next one, you just change the index:

```
/html/body/div/div[3]
```

To access a child of B, you add one more div to xpath:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div[2]/div')
```

And to access parent of any element you use:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div[2]/div')._parent
```

Hope this was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can find all elements which have class B by

```
allClassB = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='A']/div[@class='B']")
```

Now you have a list of all elements with class B, you can use `for` loop to go through each element

If the purpose is to find all elements with class C, you just need to do like:

```
allClassC = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='A']/div[@class='B']/div[@class='C']")
```

Comment: Thank for your answer, so i have "catched" all elements with class C in a var, so if I want for each C element to be clicked, I just have to do that ? `while i<len(allClassC) allClassC[i].click()  `

Comment: It depends, you can try to see if it works. Not in all cases it will work though. Sometimes, when the page is updated after the first click, the second click can throw an exception. In the case of exception `StaleElementReferenceException`, you will need to re-find the elements again (in the for loop)

Comment: I'm on the right way to achieve what I want. But I have just a problem. In my loop and in my xpath, if i write div[j] (with j declared and incremented), the j value will not be replaced by his value, and Python will keep the variable name instead of replacing it. Normally, if we do list[j] it will replace the J but it's not the case with the XPATH expression. I've tired div['j'] but the j keeps the same value everytime.

Comment: When I did it manually it works fine but the value of j into the XPATH is not dynamic.

Comment: Why don't you use allClassC as I suggested above? That way you will know exactly how many elements are there.

Comment: My need was more specific, I wouldn't give each detail, just sum up via an example and the answers have helped me. I use your answer and thank your for help. The problem with the non dynamic j in the Index was just that I have to type "+str(j)+" (and no "i" or 'i' or %) and it worked perfectly. Thank you !